# How do you notify a handler in Ansible based solely on a conditional?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, notify

I would like to notify a handler in my role by doing something like this:

```yaml
- name: Notify handler
  notify: my_handler
  when: this_thing_is_true|bool
```

But Ansible just whines:

> ERROR! no module/action detected in task.

I have tried various wedges, such as:

```yaml
- name: Notify handler
  meta: noop
  notify: my_handler
  when: this_thing_is_true|bool
```

But that similarly whines:

> [WARNING]: noop task does not support when conditional

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. This helped me realize why we were getting this warning in our case, even though we didn't have any `when:` condition on the actual _handler_ of the event. Your message helped me realize that the warning is referring to the task which _notifies_ the "event handler" in question, even though `noop` was not present in the handler task itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please mind that running a task is not enough for an handler to be notified, you also need a task that creates a changed result.

You can achieve a change result on any task with the help of the [`changed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result) option in Ansible.
Then, doing a simple [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) could be an option.

The other ideas I had, but that did not really made sense in the end:

- `pause`: but you cannot pause for less than a second
- `assert`: but it feels silly to assert the same condition that you also need to put in the `changed_that` to notify the handler. You can still `assert: that=true` but it feels equally silly.
- Maybe the most silliest of the ideas I could came with was a `fail` task with a `failed_when: false`.
- `command: 'true'` is maybe less silly, compared to the above, but I am not totally convinced, still

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    this_thing_is_true: true

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 'Notifying handlers'
        # var: this_thing_is_true 
        # ^-- might be an alternative option to msg:
      changed_when: this_thing_is_true  
      notify: 
        - me 

  handlers:
    - name: me
      debug:
        msg: 'I have been notified'
```

Gives the recap:

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
changed: [localhost] => 
  msg: Notifying handlers

RUNNING HANDLER [me] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: I have been notified
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the solution. Meta: Did not know I could add `yaml` after the ``` and get syntax highlighting. Topic: Yeah, now that you mention it, the root cause must have been there was no way the task could determine if it produced a changed condition or not.

Comment: Agreed `assert` doesn't "feel right", but on the other hand the output is cleaner, see my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

@β.εηοιτ.βε shows a solution that prefers `debug`, but I think that the output from `assert` is cleaner.

`debug` code:

```yaml
- name: with debug
  debug: msg=''
  changed_when: true
  when: something is changed
  notify: 'do stuff'
```

`assert` code:

```yaml
- name: with assert
  assert: { that: true, quiet: true }
  changed_when: true
  when: something is changed
  notify: 'do stuff'
```

`debug` output:

```
TASK [mytask : with debug] *****************************************************
changed: [server] => {
    "msg": ""
}

RUNNING HANDLER [mytask : do stuff] ********************************************
changed: [server]
```

`assert` output (seems cleaner):

```
TASK [mytask : with assert] ****************************************************
changed: [server]

RUNNING HANDLER [myhandlers : do stuff] ****************************************
changed: [server]
```

Comment: I used this the other day, thanks to you. I like it.

Comment: I tried the code as-is and got `FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'something is changed' failed. The error was: The 'changed' test expects a dictionary...` Someone make the answer a fully working example please.

Answer (score 3):

I learnt from both the given answers here. On top of that I was curious about why can't you always trigger a change for the sake of notify, then use a statement with it. After some testing it turns out you can! \o/

```
- debug:
    msg: Deciding what to do
  changed_when: true
  notify: "{{ ( res.json == [] ) | ternary( 'on empty object', 'on object exist'  ) }}"
```

Calls handler "on empty object" if true, otherwise "on object exist"