# Ansible handler - not called from rescue block

Tags: ansible, ansible-handlers

Consider the following (reduced for brevity) playbook with a block and rescue block

```yaml
- name: deploy block
  block:
  - name: debug meta
    debug: var=meta

  
  - name: create/update configmap with new data
    k8s:
      state: present
      namespace: "{{ namespace }}"
      definition: "{{ lookup('template', 'configmap.tpl.yml') }}"
      kind: ConfigMap
    notify:
      - successfull_deployment_slack_handler
  rescue:
    - name: Something went wrong handler
      debug:
        msg: "Something has failed in the playbook"
      notify: failure_deployment_slack_handler
- meta: flush_handlers
```

Testing this in the happy path works and calls the handlers as expected.
But when I fail the tasks in my testing I do see the expected debug message, but the actual handler isn't called (I've traded it for a debug message to verify).

Yes, I've tried adding `meta: flush_handlers`.

How can I make this work?

Ansible version: 2.9.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'error' in your slim version of the playbook is that `debug` will never report to ansible as `changed` and because of that, the handler wont trigger.

In this playbook where i've replaced your `rescue` `debug` with a `shell`, the handler is called

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  handlers:
    - name: handler
      debug:
        msg: handler
  tasks:
    - name: deploy block
      block:
      - name: debug meta
        debug:
          msg: in the block

      - fail:
          msg: failing
      rescue:
        - name: Something went wrong handler
          shell: date
          notify: handler
```

results in

```
TASK [debug meta] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "in the block"
}

TASK [fail] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "failing"}

TASK [Something went wrong handler] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

RUNNING HANDLER [handler] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "handler"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handlers are called only upon a change, the task `meta: flush_handlers` will execute the handlers **only if** there were handlers to be flushed in the first place, which is not your case.

> As we’ve mentioned, modules should be idempotent and can relay when they have made a change on the remote system. Playbooks recognize this and have a basic event system **that can be used to respond to change**.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change, emphasis, mine*</sup>

In order to make it work, you will have to create a changed state, somehow. That somehow could be by using [`changed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result):

```yaml
- name: deploy block
  block:
  - name: debug meta
    debug: var=meta

  
  - name: create/update configmap with new data
    k8s:
      state: present
      namespace: "{{ namespace }}"
      definition: "{{ lookup('template', 'configmap.tpl.yml') }}"
      kind: ConfigMap
    notify:
      - successfull_deployment_slack_handler
  rescue:
    - name: Something went wrong handler
      debug:
        msg: "Something has failed in the playbook"
      changed_when: true
      notify: failure_deployment_slack_handler
- meta: flush_handlers
```

<sub>*Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62183353/2123530*</sub>