# handler not executing using when condition in task

Tags: ansible, nfs, ansible-handlers

I'm trying to set up an NFS share between two nodes using Ansible. I'm using the role `nfs`, which is executed by both nodes, and I separated client and server tasks using the `when` condition.

After templating the NFS `/etc/exports` on the server node I want to restart the NFS server using a handler, but the `notify` doesn't seem to work.

This is the task I'm using:

```yaml
- name: Template NFS /etc/exports
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: exports
    dest: /etc/exports
  notify:
  - Restart NFS server
  when: inventory_hostname == groups['nfs-servers'][0]
```

I tried to restart the nfs server using this handler:

```yaml
- name: Restart NFS server
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: nfs-kernel-server
    state: restarted
```

However, the handler never executes, even when exports is actually templated.
I think that's because the task always results in `changed = false` for the client node (node2), due to the when condition. This is the output of the task:

```
TASK [nfs : Template NFS /etc/exports] 

skipping: [node2] => changed=false 
  skip_reason: Conditional result was False

changed: [node1] => changed=true 
  checksum: db864f9235e5afc0272896c4467e244d3b9c4147
  dest: /etc/exports
  gid: 0
  group: root
  md5sum: 447bf4f5557e3a020c40f4e729c90a62
  mode: '0644'
  owner: root
  size: 94
  src: /home/test/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1673949188.2970977-15410-64672518997352/source
  state: file
  uid: 0
```

Any suggestions on how to use `when` and `notify` together? Is there a way to make the `notify` ignore the skipping result?

Everything works fine if I use two roles and I remove the `when` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, handlers are [*running operations on change*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change), if there is no change, there will be no handler run.

So, you will have to trigger the handlers in a separate task in order to have the handler react to a change on another host. In this way of doing it, you will have to `register` the result of the `template` task in order to inspect its change state with the help of the `hostsvar` from other hosts.

This can be done with a *changed* state on any task you like, [for example, a `debug` task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182998/how-do-you-notify-a-handler-in-ansible-based-solely-on-a-conditional/62183353#62183353).

From the task you are providing I also see some other improvements possible:

1. Do not use a `when` in order to limit a task to a single host, prefer [delegation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) and the use of `run_once: true`, which also offer the advantages [that facts collected with `run_once: true` are propagated to all hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once), and avoid the need to use `hostsvar`.
2. Watch out for warning, your actual group name, containing a dash, is raised by Ansible as problematic

   ```
   [WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, 
   use -vvvv to see details
   ```

   and in verbose mode:

   ```
   Not replacing invalid character(s) "{'-'}" in group name (nfs-servers)
   ```

   Use underscores instead of dashes.

So, with all this:

```yaml
- hosts: nfs_servers
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Template NFS /etc/exports
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: exports
        dest: /etc/exports
      delegate_to: "{{ groups.nfs_servers.0 }}"
      run_once: true
      register: templated_exports

    - name: Propagation of the change to notify handler
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: Notify all handlers on /etc/exports change
      notify:
        - Restart NFS server
      changed_when: true
      when: templated_exports is changed

  handlers:
    - name: Restart NFS server
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: Restarting NFS server now
```

---

When run with a file change:

```
PLAY [nfs_servers] *******************************************************

TASK [Template NFS /etc/exports] *****************************************
changed: [node1]

TASK [Propagation of the change to notify handler] ***********************
changed: [node1] => 
  msg: Notify all handlers on /etc/exports change
changed: [node2] => 
  msg: Notify all handlers on /etc/exports change

RUNNING HANDLER [Restart NFS server] *************************************
ok: [node1] => 
  msg: Restarting NFS server now
ok: [node2] => 
  msg: Restarting NFS server now
```

When run with no change:

```
PLAY [nfs_servers] *******************************************************

TASK [Template NFS /etc/exports] *****************************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [Propagation of the change to notify handler] ***********************
skipping: [node1]
skipping: [node2]
```